# Windows 8 High System Memory Usage

Tags: windows, windows-8, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

My problem seems simple. My computer is using more physical memory than is actually accounted for in the sum of my programs.

!(Running windows 8.1, latest patches)

[image: What windows reports my total usage as]

[image: What the total system usage is]

I use 7.5 GB. Total usage is 12GB. The Delta is 4.5 GB. This is something I'd consider very high.

Most of the posts I've found on this site relate to driver memory leaks affecting the 'paged pool' and the 'non paged pool' creating high usage. However my pages + nonpaged pool is around 650MB, which I understand isn't far above 'normal', and shouldn't cause this 4.5GB delta. To further investigate this, I even ran `poolmon.exe` and found no such leaky drivers when I sorted by usage.

[image: Poolmon screenshot]

So my question is simply: what gives? Where art thou memory?

**Update:**

A kind user referred me to the program rammap, which gives more detailed descriptions of memory allocation. Upon running it, I discovered that 2GB of memory in the 'in use' section was allocated for 'Mapped Files', which I presume is disk caching. Upon going to the 'physical pages' tab and sorting by said files, I learned that a lot of the active mapped files were files in use by a torrent application hosting large datafiles. Terminating the application freed 1.2GB of disk caching into 'standby', thus giving the screenshot you can see below.

[image: Rammap]

The the 'delta', has dropped to 3.2 GB, which is getting closer to what I'd consider normal but is still on the high side, though if you subtract the remainder of the 'mapped file' 800MB, you end up with 2.4GB, which *could* be simply explained away by the count listed in Users in the task manager being incorrect.

With this information, now I'm not so sure. Is this just me not understanding memory accounting? Is the 'shareable' section in the table actually used by user programs and just not accounted for in the user's space in the task manager? If so then this issue would be a mixture of me not knowing disk caching can count under 'In Use'/'Active' memory and that the User's tab in the task manager is inaccurate.

Comment: What do you mean by "system memory usage" exactly? Do you just mean memory that's being used? Also, you tagged this "memory-leaks". Do you have any evidence of a leak? Do you have an actual problem or do you just need to understand how Windows 8 uses memory?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I very much dislike the tone of your comment. System memory usage is referring to memory usage that isn't accounted for by user programs. The _actual_ problem is the stated one, that system memory usage is unusually high, higher than I have observed on other computers of mine also running windows and also operating on similar workloads. 

Do I need help understanding how W8 uses memory? Maybe? Do enlighten me by answering the question informing me where exactly I'm going wrong in my reasoning, and I'll promptly close the question and mark said answer as correct.

Comment: So - [this question was brought up](https://superuser.com/questions/1153325/windows-8-1-64-bit-high-memory-usage/1154417) as a possible duplicate. *However* it feels like this question's much better than the other one, and I kinda feel we might want to let it run its course we close it either way, especially if the root cause is differemt

Comment: @JourneymanGeek thank you for editing my post and making the images display by default. I didn't know I could do that by virtue of my noob-ness ;)

Comment: post pictures of [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap), the kernel pool usage is ok.

Comment: @magicandre1981 done. Given the new information I'm starting to get that little creeping feeling that this was just a combination of me being confused about how disk caching works and how user-programs are accounted in the task manager. Is this problem resolved? Opinions appreciated.

Comment: most usage comes from private bytes which is the 7GB you see in Taskmgr). which processes do you run?  The other usage in the active column is the delta

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want a list of every program running on my machine?

Comment: look in process tab which processes consume the RAM. Also look in taskmgr->perf->cpu for the handle count. if this is very high (over 100k) [you may have zombie processes eating up the RAM](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2018/02/11/zombie-processes-are-eating-your-memory/)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Oh I see what you're saying! Sorry I understand now. I've had zombies before... *very* annoying. Thankfully that's not what I'm after here. The 7.3 GB currently used by my programs is quite legitimate (Unity, IDEs, and many many firefox instances as well as a few misc programs). My confusion is from the fact that my total 'In Use' is at 10.5 GB, meaning that there is a 'missing' 3.2GB. In past interactions with windows I am not used to deltas this high. What I am trying to discern is if this is legitimate or abnormal, and if the latter: how to fix.

Comment: the 3.2 are the sum of the other things ((non(paged pool, mapped, shared and the other you see in RAMMap).

Comment: @magicandre1981 so, in your opinion, is this normal? Am I complaining about nothing and am just misunderstanding memory accounting? That's my fundamental question.

Comment: commit is a bit high, the rest seams to be normal. look again for Zombie processes

Comment: fyi, "Mapped files" is a lot more than "disk caching". All code files (exe's, dll's, etc.) are in that category. Programs that use large data files often handle them via file mapping too (as opposed to traditional read/write access). It is not really possible to disstinguish, in the RAMmap display, "mapped file" memory usage that's just there because of the proactive or reactive cacheing the OS does from files that are mapped because they're actively being used that way.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8, like almost all modern operating systems, goes out of its way to use as much memory as it possibly can. Why? Because any memory not used is forever wasted.

If a system has 8GB of memory and only uses 7GB, it gains nothing. It can't use 9GB later. It simply has forever lost any benefit it might have gained from that extra 1GB for as long as that memory was free.

For example, say your system has lots of free RAM and you run some program. When the program finishes, the system has two choices. It could keep the program (the actual executable file on disk) in memory or it could free the memory that held the program file.

If it frees the memory, it has to go to the trouble of freeing it. If it ever wants to use that memory again, it has to go to the trouble of unfreeing it. And if that program is executed again, it has to be loaded from disk. Triple yuck.

If it doesn't free the memory, it doesn't have to go to the trouble of freeing it. if it wants to use that memory for some other purpose, it doesn't have to bother unfreeing it, saving a step. And if the program is executed again, it doesn't have to be loaded from disk. Triple win. And, of course, since no process is running that program currently, the memory won't be associated with any process.

So what's happening is that your system has sufficient free memory that it can operate in a very efficient way where it doesn't waste effort making memory free unnecessarily and then doesn't have to waste effort unfreeing memory in order to use it. Instead, it can efficiently transition memory from one use to another, and if the data in that memory happens to be needed, disk I/O can be avoided.

It's a win all around. The memory is storing data that the system hopes that some future process may find useful, and it's also avoiding extraneous trips through the free memory list to make memory free just to have to mark it used again. Modern operating systems only need to keep a very small amount of memory free, just enough to handle emergency situations (such as page faults and requests for memory from interrupt code) where it can't easily transition memory from one use to another.

Comment: Thank you for your answer David. I do have an appreciation for the idea that absolutely free memory is wasted memory, since it can be used instead to cache data for future use, instead of loading it from disk. What I do **not** understand is why is the memory that it's using to cache not listed under 'Cached'/'Standby' ('Memory that contains cached data and code that is not currently in use') in task manager? I was under the impression that cached data was included there, instead of under the 'In Use' metric ('Memory used by processes, drivers, or the operating system')

Comment: @clairefey - fyi: Mark Russinovich explains the mysteries of memory management: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjTl53I_qzY https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KZdNsq1YV4

Comment: @akira Thank you, I'll be sure to watch those tomorrow morning.

Comment: You will be delighted. Btw: Mark wrote the tools you were referred to.

Comment: You're missing a very key point -- absent evidence of a memory leak (which you don't have), the less free memory the better. OSes are specifically designed to keep as little memory free as possible, trying to achieve the minimum absolutely necessary.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the complaint does not arise from the lack of free memory, but rather the lack of available memory. I'm not missing your point at all. Disk caching is normal operation, obviously. But disk caching can be stopped in order to make room for more programs, which is why it's listed under 'standby' (And 'standby' falls under 'available', along with 'free') My issue is that there is **In use** memory that is unaccounted for.

Comment: @ClaireFey That's not an issue, that's possibly a symptom of an issue. Do you have an issue? Is the system slow? Is there excessive disk I/O?