# high RAM usage identified as caused by fastboot.sys, need help solving it - windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory

Ever since I installed windows 10 on my machine, I noticed a huge ram usage even when idle, around 50-60%, so I finally decided to solve the problem.I installed rammap and checked it out, and I saw that I had almost 3gb of ram driver locked.I then [used the assessement console to run a memory footprint](https://superuser.com/a/1125553/174557), and guess what, I found that Fastboot.sys took a whooping 2.7 gb of ram.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/4BoIM]

Problem is now, how do I solve this?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, `fastboot.sys` is a driver provided by Lenovo. So just uninstall all their crapware I guess?

Comment: If you can help me with how to do that, it would be much appreciated.I cant find it in device manager, nor in remove programs, so im at a total loss atm.

Comment: The comment above means the driver in question is **part** of / provided by at least one Lenovo specific and factory installed software, not that it has that exact name. We don't know which one.

Comment: I haven't used Lenovo Fastboot, but they have a KBA to turn it off here : https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/ht501793 .  I Googled "lenovo fastboot windows 10" and found it.

Comment: Thats the first thing i did, but as far as I can tell that feature and fastboot.sys crap from them are completely different things, therefore it didnt affect it at all.I actually ran autoruns and tried to disable fastboot from there, but the pc would bsod even when booting in safe mode.Im pretty much at a loss here, have no clue what to do and i cant find anyone with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing to solve. This is not a problem.

The `fastboot.sys` driver preloads files that Windows is known to need on startup. It only uses memory that would otherwise be unused and the driver releases the memory as soon as either they are no longer helpful or the system is under memory pressure.

The memory will be made available for other uses as soon as it is needed for another use. There is no problem to solve.