# Where has my memory gone?

Tags: memory

I'm experiencing some slowness on my laptop (SSD, I7 4th gen, 16GB) lately. I can't really figure out what it is, but one thing that I noticed is that the memory usage is quite high (8GB of the 16GB), even when I'm doing nothing.
So in this image it shows my memory (geheugen) usage:

[image]

I am using 856Mb (it was 400MB before I started typing this question in Chrome) , but 53% of my memory, so more than 8GB, is used. So I wonder: where did the rest go?
There are no other users logged on, I run SqlServer but I already limited it's memory usage.

Also found this datasheet in process explorer:
[image]

These are the processes using > 10MB:

[image]

This shows 'hard errors'. Is this a problem?
[image]

The 'memory' view
[image]

2 screenshots from rammap:
[image]

[image]

Do you have any idea what it can be?

Comment: Does task manager's detail view or resource manager give a breakdown of specific processes' memory usage?

Comment: Trying using ProcessExplorer instead of the crummy built-in stuff. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer

Comment: I also use the ProcessExplorer (the middle image is a screenshot from it) but that shows the same processes more or less, at least for the part which processes use the most memory

Comment: To see what’s using memory, use [RAMMap](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/rammap). Also, please provide a screenshot of Task Manager’s “Memory” view.

Comment: "driver locked" is too large with 4GB. tgis happens when you use Hyper-V and run VMs. If you don't use Hyper-V, [use Windows ADK to trace which driver causes the usage](https://superuser.com/a/1125553/174557)

Comment: Will try the proposed solution. Weird thing is I rebooted my computer twice since the post and one time the same thing as in my post occured, and the second time it didn't. At this time of writing, it also didn't happen. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that I'm HDMI connected to a monitor or not. I'll install the ADK and run it when it occurs again. Hope it will the occur again on reboot (I read that the ADK tool reboots to measure data)