# My RAM usage is at 68% and I don't know why

Tags: memory, windows-11, task-manager, ramdisk, memory-leaks

Here are screenshots of my current issue:

1. [First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxCmz.png)
2. [Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhwQl.png)
3. [Three](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6Lxd.png)
4. [Four](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXiZT.png)
5. [Five](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X01sx.png)
6. [Six](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CFx9.png)

RamMap

[image: RamMap]

Do I have a memory leak? Zombie Handlers? What do I do? Never had this issue before..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hello, instead of dropping 10 screens without any context, describe please describe **as specifically as possible** what the issue is and what did you try to solve it. "Too high RAM usage IMO" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: You have a 64-bit OS so 4 GB in use immediately. How much memory does the computer have?

Comment: 1/3 of the memory being used by your system is reserved by a driver. You should identify which driver is using that memory. Task Manager screenshots are not helpful, as they are only user processes, or that’s what it appears to be (6 screenshots are way to many to mentally process) essentially since you didn’t include the Performance tab. [This](https://superuser.com/questions/1121714/driver-locked-memory-on-a-non-virtual-machine) contains the necessary information to diagnose the problem or at least provide us the required information to do so

Comment: I think you mean zombie handles / zombie processes; Zombie Handlers are a thing in Dead Rising https://deadrising.fandom.com/wiki/Zombie_Handlers

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Windows task manager view is one thing, but opening the "subprocesses" is another.
Task manager only shows the resource use of the parent process and does not add up all sub processes.

Unless more information is provided I can only make a guess, but that guess would be that your Browser (Brave), which is build on the chromium code, allocates your RAM. Every plugin and (almost) every tab is started in a separate process, which adds to stability and security, but adds overhead and hides the total memory used across all of them.

Unfolding all of these subprocesses and adding together their memory allocation should give you more.
As a hint: the main process takes about 960 MB, which is already about 6% of the 16 GB available (which can be inferred from the 16,691,696 K given in RamMap).

Have 7 processes of equal use and you're up to 60%, add what windows and other processes naturally use (like the bitdefender's host process with 400 MB) and you're quickly at 12-ish GB or 67% of 16 GB

The same would account for other programs build on the code (like Discord, Steam, etc and other electron apps, which are basically chromium in a wrapper)

---

Next would be the about 3.4 GB taken by an unspecified driver. Integrated graphics?

*(Those are still only about 22% use, keeping 46% or about 7.5 GB in use elsewhere. It can be said that Windows and it's own processes will take about 2 GB, so that leaves about 5.5 GB of memory used elsewhere, which isn't unusual for a system that is in use)*

Here is another question with a "driver locked" memory situation and the (as of now) single answer that provides a guide on how to identify which driver is causing it:
[Driver locked memory on a non-virtual machine](https://superuser.com/questions/1121714/driver-locked-memory-on-a-non-virtual-machine)
Going through these steps would help finding the cause.